# remove specific cookie in nginx reverse proxy

Tags: security, nginx, cookies

I have a `nginx` as reverse proxy that proxies my requests to different destinations. Client send different to `nginx`. I want to remove a specific cookie for one of my locations. For example if client send cookie A and B, I want to sent A form for `/api`.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but you can try `set $cookie_A ""` in the specific location.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: I didn't work for me

Comment: Do you mean that if the client send HTTP header like `Cookie: A=value1; B=value2; C=value3` with some request like `/api/some/command`, you need to transform that header to `Cookie: A=value1; C=value3`? Can you add the `location /api { ... }` block from your nginx config to your question?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: I can't understand your question. What I understand, you have some specific `location /api { ... }` block and you want to get rid of some specific cookie when you got a `/api/...` request. Am I right or not?

Comment: yes,you are.how can i handle it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming you are using `proxy_pass` directive and your cookie name is `my_cookie`, you can cut this cookie and its value from `Cookie` HTTP header this way:

```
location /api {

    # save original "Cookie" header value
    set $altered_cookie $http_cookie;

    # check if the "my_cookie" cookie is present
    if ($http_cookie ~ '(.*)(^|;\s)my_cookie=("[^"]*"|[^\s]*[^;]?)(\2|$|;$)(?:;\s)?(.*)') {
        # cut "my_cookie" cookie from the string
        set $altered_cookie $1$4$5;
    }

    # hide original "Cookie" header
    proxy_hide_header Cookie;

    # set "Cookie" header to the new value
    proxy_set_header  Cookie $altered_cookie;

    ... # other proxy settings here

    proxy_pass <upstream>; # change to your upstream server
}
```

This complex regex allows to check if the `my_cookie` cookie is present no matter it is at the beginning, at the middle or at the end of `Cookie` header value. Here are several examples showing how this regex works on different strings:

```
Whole "Cookie" string                                          $1                      $2      $3            $4      $5                       $1$4$5
-----------------------------------------------------------    --------------------    ----    ----------    ----    ---------------------    -----------------------------------------
"some_cookie=value1; my_cookie=value2; other_cookie=value3"    "some_cookie=value1"    "; "    "value2"      "; "    "other_cookie=value3"    "some_cookie=value1; other_cookie=value3"
"some_cookie=value1; my_cookie=value2"                         "some_cookie=value1"    "; "    "value2"      ""      ""                       "some_cookie=value1"
"my_cookie=value2; other_cookie=value3"                        ""                      ""      "value2; "    ""      "other_cookie=value3"    "other_cookie=value3"
"my_cookie=value2"                                             ""                      ""      "value2"      ""      ""                       ""
```

For those who are looking for the same recipe but use `fastcgi_pass` instead of `proxy_pass` - use `fastcgi_param HTTP_COOKIE $altered_cookie if_not_empty;` instead of `proxy_hide_header` and `proxy_set_header` directives.

Comment: brilliant answer! Thanks! Maybe you can tell how to filter serveral cookies at once, or filter cookies like HttpOnly?

Comment: @AlexR. Considering those cookies could be placed in `Cookie` header in an unpredictable order, the most simple would be to use several `if` blocks, I think. Replace `if ($http_cookie ~ ...` with `if ($altered_cookie ~ ...` and remove those cookies one by one. Removing cookies considering their attributes like `HttpOnly` will require a completely different approach. A much more advanced filtering can be implemented using some scripting via [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module), [njs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_js_module.html), etc.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the `map` syntax instead of `if` (`if` is evil). Also, it looks to me as if you could also leave out the non-capturing group `(?:;\s)?`.
Therefore I have implemented this as follows:

```
map $http_cookie $altered_cookie {
    "~(.*)(^|;\s)my_cookie=(\"[^\"]*\"|[^\s]*[^;]?)(\2|$|;$)(.*)" $1$4$5;
    default $http_cookie;
}
```

Comment: Manuel, this does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)